# Xcode Running "Too Fast"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a problem with my code running through the options "too fast" within my Xcode project (when testing on my iPhone). I have two buttons that control changing an amount of milk from regular [default option] down to light or up to extra. When I touch to change the milk amount down to light, it works fine. However, from that option, when I hit the up arrow to change the milk amount back to regular, it changes to regular and then to extra because the code is being executed so quickly. This is a bit hard to explain through wording but I'm trying to figure out how to make the process stop at each iteration without skipping all the way to the end of the line per se. I'll post my code below but let me know if you need more clarification in order to help out!

```
@IBAction func changeMilkAmountRight(sender: UIButton) {
    if milkAmount == 1 {
        milkAmount = 2
        milkAmountLabel.text = String("regular")
        updateLabels()
    }
    if milkAmount == 2 {
        milkAmount = 3
        milkAmountLabel.text = String("extra")
        updateLabels()
    }
}

@IBAction func changeMilkAmountLeft(sender: UIButton) {
    if milkAmount == 3 {
        milkAmount = 2
        milkAmountLabel.text = String("regular")
        updateLabels()
    }
    if milkAmount == 2 {
        milkAmount = 1
        milkAmountLabel.text = String("light")
        updateLabels()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code will always execute both if blocks. In the "Left" case it will change 3 and 2 and then also execute to change 2 to 1. If you change the second `if` in each function to an `else if` it will only execute once.

Comment: @BrianWalker is correct. Both `if` blocks in your methods will always execute. If you use the debugger to step through the code you will see this yourself.

Comment: That seemed to work wonderfully! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Also consider using += and -= and an array of strings instead of those ugly if's.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `else if` so only one block can run, for example:

```
if milkAmount == 3 {
    milkAmount = 2
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("regular")
    updateLabels()
} else if milkAmount == 2 {
    milkAmount = 1
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("light")
    updateLabels()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `else if`.

Take your code here:

```
if milkAmount == 1 {
    milkAmount = 2
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("regular")
    updateLabels()
}
if milkAmount == 2 {
    milkAmount = 3
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("extra")
    updateLabels()
}
```

Imagine it enters the first block. `milkAmount` is originally equal to `1`, but the code block is entered and it is changed to `2`. After the code block exits, you then check if `milkAmount` is equal to `2` (which it is), and it then changes to `3`.

Instead, use `else if` on your second if statement, like so:

```
if milkAmount == 1 {
    milkAmount = 2
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("regular")
    updateLabels()
}
else if milkAmount == 2 {
    milkAmount = 3
    milkAmountLabel.text = String("extra")
    updateLabels()
}
```

Now, if the first block is executed, your code isn't even going to check if `milkAmount` is equal to 2, and your problem will be solved.

Consider reading about if statements in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html